# Is integration unary or binary operator?

Tags: abstract-algebra, binary-operations

Is integration unary operation or binary operation? If we think about numbers, then integrals are interated binary operation. But if we think in terms of functions, then integrals seem unary operators. I'm confused.

Comment: Could you explain your two claims further? I'm not sure why you say that integrals are binary operations in these two contexts.

Comment: In the case of an indefinite integral, we have a unary operator (a function is the input and (any) antiderivate the output)

Comment: @sebastianMonnet I had a typo, I meant to say they seem like unary when thinking in terms of functions and iterated binary when in terms of numbers.

Comment: @Peter then what happens in case of definite integral? Do the limits need to taken account of?

Comment: $f\mapsto\int_a^b f(x)\,{\rm d}x$ is a unary operation for each $(a,b)$; $(a,b)\mapsto\int_a^b f(x)\,{\rm d}x$ is a binary operation for any $f$; $(a,b,f)\mapsto\int_a^b f(x)\,{\rm d}x$ is ternary, etc. It depends on which of $a,b,f$ you consider an argument of the operation and which you consider a parameter (saying which operation is being done).